# number of subsets where GCD equals to X

Tags: algorithms, discrete-mathematics, number-theory, counting

The original statement for this problem can be found [here](https://github.com/pranavkundra/IEEE-Xtreme-8.0/blob/master/Questions/Play%20with%20GCD.pdf)

This is a question from IEEExtream 2014. There is an array of integers given. Input is X, so output is the number of subsets where there GCD equals to X.

**Eg:**

```
OriginalSet = {2, 3, 5, 6, 6}
numberOfSubsets(2) => 3 // there are 3 subsets where their GCD equals to 2
i.e. {2, 6}, {2, 6}, {2, 6}
```

**Limits:**

```
OriginalSet.length < pow(10, 5),
element_of_an_array < pow(10, 4),
X < pow(10,4)
```

I bruteforced the solution and it gives me TLE. I am stuck on this question for few days now. Could you explain me how to solve this efficiently.

**Edit**

- the subset size is not limited to 2. It is from the power-set.
- It guarantees that for a given query there is only 100 unique numbers.

Comment: I'm sure we had an almost identical question in the last couple of weeks but I can't find it right now. Anyone?

Comment: Last week there was a question about calculating the  multiplication of  the GCD of every  possible subset. It was removed

Comment: @jjohn That sounds like it's the question I was thinking of, yes.  Thanks!

Comment: Could you please identify constraints, i.e., X and the set size?

Comment: What's a "TLE", and why is it bad?  What size of parameters?  What have you tried?

Comment: TLE: Time limit exceeded. Note this mean that his  solution wasn't fast enough to pass all test on the online judge

Comment: I think there was something with setwise gcd's a few months ago.  Solution seemed to involve incrementally building/unioning sets and gcd'ing their gcd's.

Comment: Found it -- find minimal subset where gcd=1: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/finding-the-size-of-the-smallest-subset-with-gcd-1/45539#45539

Comment: What is the limitation on the GCD?

Comment: You can take hint from problem code [AMR15B]( https://www.codechef.com/ACMAMR15/problems/AMR15B) asked in ACM-ICPC 2015 in first round on codechef .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the solution for "585E - Present for Vitalik the Philatelist" [here](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/20898) where is says "Let's calculate the number of subsets with gcd equal to 1". I hope you can extend the logic from there to solve the problem for X.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic programming approach to solve this problem; however, you have not yet specified what the limitation on X is. 
This is too similar to the question [Algorithm for finding maximum mutually coprime subset of a multiset of integers](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/48298/algorithm-for-finding-maximum-mutually-coprime-subset-of-a-multiset-of-integers/48304#48304)
In that way, you could also use GCD instead of LCM to solve your problem since the question I gave is a special case of your question.